# MongoDB projection query with an 'and' condition rewrite using Spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How can I rewrite this projection query using spring-data-mongodb?
The main problem I am having is with $and operator.

Query:

```
{
 $project: {
  "_id": 1,
  "totalAmount": {
   $cond: [{
    $and: [{
     $eq: ["$type", "entity"]
    }, {
     $eq: ["$status", "ACTIVE"]
    }]
   }, "$amount", 0]
  },
 }
}
```

I wrote

```
ConditionalOperators.Cond operator = ConditionalOperators
.when(new Criteria()      
.andOperator(Criteria.where("type").is("entity") , Criteria.where("status").is("ACTIVE")))
.thenValueOf("amount").otherwise(0.0);

ProjectionOperation projectionOperationNavLogs = project().and("_id").as("_id").and(operator).as("totalAmount");
```

but this is not the same query

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [$cond documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

> The $cond expression has one of two syntaxes:
>
> ```
> { $cond: { if: <boolean-expression>, then: <true-case>, else: <false-case-> } }
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> { $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }
> ```

The fact that your generated query uses a more verbose syntax is not a problem.